# Error when trying to authenticate in Rackspace

Tags: python-2.7, rackspace, pyrax

I have got Following code from Rackspace Documentation.

```
import pyrax
pyrax.set_setting("identity_type", "rackspace")
pyrax.set_default_region('ORD')
pyrax.set_credentials('ot7336', '2755cd822321335191c8cc3ab46bbcff')
```

but when i run the module I get following error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Python27/rackspaceFileDownload.py", line 1, in <module>
import pyrax
ImportError: No module named pyrax
```

I have downloaded pyrax from this link https://github.com/rackspace/pyrax/

Unzipped it and installed it in windows in CMD using "setup.py install"

Comment: did installation get success?

Comment: Yes, It was. But there was a problem like warning **(something) is not found

Comment: this pip does not work here

Comment: Try `pip install pyrax` to install pip 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-to-install-pip-on-windows

Comment: this pip does not work in windows and i have tried this link before only install works for me